# backup kmail in command prompt

Tags: command-line, fedora, backup, kmail

How to take kmail backup mails from command mode as GUI mode got crashed in fedora12? Found the location of mails, But how to take backup to another system to configure?

Answer (score 0):

All your kmail settings are stored here: `~/.kde4/share/apps/kmail`
Just copy this folder to another pc.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I just want to know little brief by copying from old location to new location, does it allow to new mail configuration to load this old mails with out fail?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...